# stringr str_locate_all not returning the proper index in a dplyr string

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to use str_locate_all to find the index of the third occurrence of  '/' in a dplyr chain but it's not returning the correct index.

```
  ga.categoryViews.2016 <- ga.data %>%
    mutate(province = str_sub(pagePath,2,3),
           index = str_locate_all(pagePath, '/')[[1]][,"start"][3],
           category = str_sub(pagePath, 
                              str_locate_all(pagePath, '/')[[1]][,"start"][3] + 1,
                              ifelse(str_detect(pagePath,'\\?'), str_locate(pagePath, '\\?') - 1, str_length(pagePath))
                              )
             )
```

an example of what it's returning is

[image]

The first column is pagePath, the fourth is the index

It seems to be always returning an index of 12.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `rowwise()`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 mutate(new = str_locate_all(v1, '/')[[1]][,2][3])

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#                              v1   new
#                           <chr> <int>
#1 /on/srgsfsfs-gfdgdg/dfgsdfg-df    20
#2        /on/sgsddg-dfgsd/dfg-dg    17
```

**DATA**

```
x <- c('/on/srgsfsfs-gfdgdg/dfgsdfg-df', '/on/sgsddg-dfgsd/dfg-dg')
df <- data.frame(v1 = x, stringsAsFactors = F)

df
#                              v1
#1 /on/srgsfsfs-gfdgdg/dfgsdfg-df
#2        /on/sgsddg-dfgsd/dfg-dg
```